# Did I violate the LSP principle in this example?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, solid-principles, liskov-substitution-principle

I have this code that implements 2 types of doors.
One door contains a lock and the other one does not.

The **Door** interface is a no brainer:

```
public interface Door {
    void open();
    void close();
}
```

Then I have the implementations: **LockedDoor** and **RegularDoor**

```
public class LockedDoor implements Door {
    private Lock lock;
    private boolean isOpen;

    @Override
    public void open() {
        if(!lock.isLocked()) {
            this.isOpen = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        this.isOpen = false;
    }
}

public class RegularDoor implements Door {
    private boolean isOpen;

    @Override
    public void open() {
        isOpen = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        isOpen = false;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the `LockedDoor`'s open function will open the door only if the lock is unlocked.
You can unlock the lock by receiving it from `LockedDoor` and calling it's unlock function.

Is it a violation of Liskov Substitution Principle?
If it is, what will be a good alternative?

Comment: Your question is more appropriate here: [Software Engineering SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Why do you think that you need two different classes? Would having one Door class not be sufficient? You only have to check the `isOpen` state if a door is locked or not :)

Comment: @KarelG when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit hard to answer this question, as your interface for `Door` seems incomplete in the sense that it's unclear what `open()` and `close()` are supposed to do. Let's clear it up by adding an `isOpen()` method, and defining that once `open()` is called, a subsequent call to `isOpen()` should return `true` (and I'm purposely ignoring the question of what happens if you attempt to open and already open door, just for the sake of brevity).

In this case, you are definitely violating the LSP principle - if you attempt to open a locked door you'd fail, and the door would remain closed.

One way to solve this issue is to add a return value to the `open()` and `close()` methods so they can report back whether or not the operation succeeded:

```
public interface Door {
    /**
     * Checks if the door is open.
     * @return {@code true} if the door is open, {@code false} if not.
    boolean isOpen();

    /**
     * Attempt to open the door.
     * @return {@code true} if the door was successfully opened, 
     * {@code false} if not.
     * In other words, if a call to {@code open} returns {@code true}, a
     * subsequent call to {@link #isOpen} will return {@code true}.
     */
    boolean open();

    /**
     * Attempt to close the door.
     * @return {@code true} if the door was successfully closed, 
     * {@code false} if not.
     * In other words, if a call to {@code close} returns {@code true}, a
     * subsequent call to {@link #isOpen} will return {@code false}.
     */
    void close();
}

public class RegularDoor implements Door {
    private boolean isOpen;

    @Override
    public boolean isOpen() {
        return isOpen;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean open() {
        return isOpen = true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean close() {
        return isOpen = false;
    }
}


public class LockedDoor implements Door {
    private Lock lock;
    private boolean isOpen;

    @Override
    public boolean isOpen() {
        return isOpen;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean open() {
        if (!lock.isLocked()) {
            return isOpen = true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean close() {
        return isOpen = false;
    }

    // Not shown here - methods to lock and unlock the door
}
```

Comment: I think it would be better to make open() throw an exception when unable to do the opening. By having a return value from command method you break CQS, though there is still profit of differentiating between succesful and failed open() execution. Exceptions make it clear that either a command succeeds or we should go to different execution flow.

Answer (score 1):

**No**, you are (probably) not violating LSP.

Longer answer: Depends of course on your "definition" of the `open()` method in the interface `Door`. If you define the method as "*tries to open the door if possible*", then you are in the clear.

It might be argued the `open()` method should be called `tryOpen()` to clarify your intent to the caller that the door might not be open after the call.

If you however define the `open()` method to *always* open the door, then of course you are violating your contract (and LSP) in `LockedDoor`.

Another problem is, that there is something missing in the interface. As it stands right now there is no *effect* the open/closed state has on any of the available methods `open()`/`close()`. I assume you have some other method in the `Door` for which the door's state is relevant, like `walkThrough()` or something similar.